# Android emulator position is always in 0 0 on screen after Android Studio installation

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-emulator

After Android Studio installation my emulator always starts in 0,0 position on screen. I modify **emulator-user.ini** file(windows.x and windows.y), but after emulator launched coordinates are 0,0. Also I try to set needed coordinates and set read only attribute for this file, but it also doesn't work here.
Emulator always launch in 0,0 position.

Could you help me with this?